# r.e. /stats fields.

Tags: discussion, api

I see we are getting some meta data in stats now. This is good.

I see the api path in there, but I have to assume that it is simply part of the record that is being output and is not intended as a means of discovery.

That would be like calling someone to get their number. ;-)

So I guess we are just waiting for the other shoe to drop.

http://stackauth.com

```
{
    "api_sites": [{
        "name": "Stack Overflow",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.stackoverflow.com/",
        "site_url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "description": "Member of the StackExchange Network",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/so/img/apple-touch-icon.png"
    }, {
        "name": "Server Fault",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/sf/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.serverfault.com/",
        "site_url": "http://serverfault.com",
        "description": "Member of the StackExchange Network",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/sf/img/apple-touch-icon.png"
    }, {
        "name": "Super User",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/su/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.superuser.com/",
        "site_url": "http://superuser.com",
        "description": "Member of the StackExchange Network",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/su/img/apple-touch-icon.png"
    }, {
        "name": "Stack Overflow Meta",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/mso/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/",
        "site_url": "http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
        "description": "Member of the StackExchange Network",
        "icon_url": "/content/mso/img/apple-touch-icon.png"
    }, {
        "name": "Stack Apps",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/sa/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.stackapps.com/",
        "site_url": "http://stackapps.com",
        "description": "Member of the StackExchange Network",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/sa/img/apple-touch-icon.png"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other shoe is http://stackauth.com/sites

Its not in docs yet, but it should be good to go.

Comment: the meta icon_url is relative.

Comment: off-topic: my luck: the one path I used to document usage of the soapi wrappers is the one that gets removed. =-\ I was being lazy and used it because I could whip up examples that I knew would work instead of looking up post id's.  Bottom line: I am tickled pink that ugly redheaded step-child of a path is gone. thanks.

Comment: Kevin, the site node on stats is gone on .3. Was this intentional?

Comment: @code poet - nope, and its fixed now.